# How to fix a error “invalid operands to binary expression”

Tags: c

When i used this code to find the volume of cylinder i got the error

'invalid operands to binary ^ have( 'float' and 'ínt' ) can somebody explain me why i get this error.

```
float r,vol;
printf("Enter the parameters to be calculated:\n");
scanf("%f",&r);
vol = (4*3.14*(r^3))/3;
printf("The Vol of the cylinder is : %f\n",vol);
return 0;
```

Comment: Maybe check what `^` does in C.

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR, use `pow()` for exponentiation (add `#include <math.h>`) to your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `^` for power in `C` .This is not the power it is `bitwise xor`.USe this instead-

```
#include <math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
 {
  float r,vol;
  printf("Enter the parameters to be calculated:\n");
  scanf("%f",&r);
  vol = (4*3.14*(pow(r,3)))/3;
  printf("The Vol of the cylinder is : %f\n",vol);
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` is the XOR operator in C. For the potence use `pow(base, pot)` from `math.h`.